# Discord.py send message when another user posts a message

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a bot in discord.py and want my bot to ping a role when a Webhook sends message in a specific channel. Is there anyway to do this? Right now all I have is the channel id and I am pretty sure it is a client Event

```
@client.event
async def pingrole():
  channel = client.get_channel("channel id")
```

Comment: You have to use an `on_message` event and check for messages

Comment: I forgot to mention, it is a Webhook, So I Want the bot to ping when the Webhook posts something

Comment: You would still have to use an `on_message` event.

Comment: You can use `on_message` as @Dominik said, [get role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get%20role#discord.Guild.get_role) by id and then mention it using `.mention`.
Example:
`role = guild.get_role(id)`
`role.mention` and then you can send it as message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == webhook.id:
        await ctx.send(role.mention)
```